# Как работать с pull request

Tags: git, github

Мой форк проекта сделал сторонний разработчик и сделал **pull request** с своими изменениями

Я выполняю команду

```
git checkout -b test-master master
```

и тем самым создаю у себя локально ветку и выполняю команду

```
git pull https://github.com/test/gitHub.git master
```

чтоб скачать *pull request*.

Я хочу запустить проект и посмотреть как работает новая вункциональность от разработчика.

Что мне делать если:

1. Я хочу принять только некоторые файлы и слить их в проект.
2. Я хочу исправить некоторые изменения и показать это разработчику, кто предложил *pull request*.

Comment: Я не очень понял о каком виде PR вы говорите. Это GitHub PR или чистый Git и его `git request-pull ...`, посланный по email? Если речь про первый вариант, то зарегестрируйтесь на GitHub, и там принимайте PR и обсуждайте их в классическом GH интерфейсе.